# What is the difference between Swarm intelligence and Multiagentsystems?

Tags: artificial-intelligence, distributed-systems, agent-based-computing

Swarm intelligence and Multiagent systems are both a part of Distributed AI. Multiagent systems describe a system with agents, which communicate with each other.
Swarm intelligence describes systems, which coordinate through decentralized control and self-organization.

However, I am unable to name an example for a Multiagentsystem, which could not be linked to Swarm intelligence and the other way around. Could you name one?